# Expand a Linux mint partition on a Chromebook?

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint, gparted

I'm running a Chromebook Pixel 2013 that was previously dual booted with one-half Windows and the other half Mint. Due to the lack of a proper driver support for the mouse and touchscreen, I decided to delete the Windows 10 partition. I removed it from grub, and everything works fine, however whenever I go into GParted to expand the Mint partition to utilize the full 64GB, I don't have an option to expand it. I attempted to boot from a Kali USB, but to no avail, there's no option to expand the partition? What do I do?

Comment: please post the output of `lsblk -fs` if there is a `mmcblk0` device also post the output of `sudo cgpt show /dev/mmcblk0`m you probably need to install cgpt first.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give some detail there. When you say

"I decided to delete the Windows 10 partition. I removed it from grub, and everything works fine,"

that, for example, could be interpreted to mean you believe that by removing the grub entry you've removed the partition. Which would not be the case. But in any event, you should be able to do what you want from gparted. Before you can expand a partition you have to make space to expand it into. Which again makes me wonder if you actually removed the Windows partition. I suggest you post screenshots of what gparted is showing you.

Don't get offended if that seems painfully obvious to you. Everything is obscure to SOMEBODY and I really can't tell from what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't created a new partition table before then you need a partitioning tool that supports partition tables on Chrome OS devices. The mainline tool for this task is `cgpt`, [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/cgpt.1.html) is the latest manpage from Ubuntu at the time of writing.

I heard that recent versions of GParted support cgpt, but I haven't tried on my Chromebooks and I couldn't find details about this but you may try the [latest GParted live](http://gparted.org/news.php) release, Kali [isn't meant](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) to be your one stop shop troubleshooting utility.